# Is There A Way to Add A Field to Serializer After Declaring It?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am want something like this:

```
def get_user_serializer_class(include_section_name):

    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialzer)
        section_name = serializer.CharField(source='section.name')
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username', 'section_name']

    return UserSerializer
```

But at the runtime, while defining the UserSerializer, I don't know whether to add `section_name` or not. It will be decided by `include_section_name`.
I am writing something like this to acheive it:

```
def get_user_serializer_class(include_section_name):

    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialzer)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username'] + ['section_name'] if include_section_name else []
    if include_section_name:
        setattr(UserSerializer, 'section_name', serializer.CharField(source='section.name'))

    return UserSerializer
```

But it's not working for me. Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the other way, not including a character dynamically but excluding them.
Here is an example that might help.

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    section_name = serializer.CharField(source='section.name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.context.get('exclude_fields', []):
            self.fields.pop(field)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'section_name', )
```

views.py

```
user = User.objects.get(id=0) # any user instance here
serializer_context = dict()
if not include_section_name:
    serializer_context['exclude_fields'] = ['section_name']
user_data = UserSerializer(user, context=serializer_context).data
```

You didn't give detail about your view code but you get the idea here. This will work and also provide you the flexibility you want.